# getchar() function in C: why it won't print a character right after I use getchar?

Tags: c, input, inputstream, getchar

I am just a beginner in programming. And I am learning the K&R's book, the C Programming Language. While I am reading, I become more and more curious about this question -- 
when there is a loop to get characters one by one from the input and I put an outputing function in the loop, whose result I thought would be like print each character right after it had been entered. However, the result seems like the computer will only print out a whole package of characters after I tap a  key.

Such as the answer of exercise 1-22 from K&R's book:

```
/* K&R Exercise 1-22 p.34 
 *
 * Write a program to "fold" long input lines into two or more
 * shorter lines after the last non-blank character that occurs before the n-th
 * column of input.  Make sure your program does something intelligent with very
 * long lines, and if there are no blanks or tabs before the specified column.
 */

#include <stdio.h>

#define LINE_LENGTH 80
#define TAB '\t'
#define SPACE ' '
#define NEWLINE '\n'

void entab(int);

int main()
{
    int i, j, c;
    int n = -1;     /* The last column with a space. */
    char buff[LINE_LENGTH + 1];

    for ( i=0; (c = getchar()) != EOF; ++i )
    {
        /* Save the SPACE to the buffer. */
        if ( c == SPACE )
        {
            buff[i] = c;
        }
        /* Save the character to the buffer and note its position. */ 
        else
        {
            n = i;
            buff[i] = c;
        }

        /* Print the line and reset counts if a NEWLINE is encountered. */
        if ( c == NEWLINE )
        {
            buff[i+1] = '\0';
            printf("%s", buff);

            n = -1;
            i = -1;
        }
        /* If the LINE_LENGTH was reached instead, then print up to the last
         * non-space character. */
        else if ( i == LINE_LENGTH - 1 )
        {
            buff[n+1] = '\0';
            printf("%s\n", buff);

            n = -1;
            i = -1;
        }
    }
}
```

I supposed the program would turn out to be like, it would print out only one line of characters, whose length is 80, right after I entered just 80 characters (and I haven't tapped an ENTER key yet). However, it doesn't show up that way! I can totally enter the whole string no matter how many characters there are. When I finally decide to finish the line, I just tap ENTER key, and it will give me the right outputs: the long string is cut into several short pieces/lines, which have 80 characters (and of course the last one may contain less than 80 characters).

I wonder WHY does that happened?

Comment: The input is buffered, your programme only receives it after the user entered a newline (or if the system buffer is full).

Comment: Why is this tagged `C++`?

Comment: Nothing C++ about this question by the look of it.

Comment: @DanielFischer Thank you. I understand a little now. But why won't the buff[] string be altered? The computer can print not only one buff[] string, while I thought only the buff[] string that was the latest updated can survive. Only one buff[] string is defined in the program. Or may I say, the whole result is buffed and just wait for a newline to show them out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually (and in your case), `stdin` is line-buffered, so your programme doesn't receive the characters as they are typed, but in chunks, when the user enters a newline (<kbd>Return</kbd>), or, possibly, when the system buffer is full.

So when the user input is finally sent to your programme, it is copied into the programme's input buffer. That's where `getchar()` reads the characters from to fill `buff`.

If the input is long enough, `buff` will be filled with `LINE_LENGTH` characters from the input buffer and then printed several times (until the entire contents of the input buffer have been consumed).

On Linux (methinks generally on Unix-ish systems, but I'm not sure), you can also send the input to the programme without entering a newline by typing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> on a non-empty line (as the first input on a line, that closes `stdin`; at a later point in an input line, you can close `stdin` by typing it twice), so if you type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> after entering `LINE_LENGTH` [or more] characters without a newline, [at least the initial part of] the input is printed immediately then.

Comment: Thanks! I think I get it now. :) It is important to learn how the computer works when you are learning C...

Answer (score 0):

I'm very glad to see you here because I also come from China. Actually, my English is poor. And, I am a beginner in programming, too. So, I have not understand your purpose very well.

However, I found a problem in your codes. The loop may not stop. EOF is end of file, but you didn't open any files.

What I knew about getchar() is getting a standard input into butter cache. getchar() is often used to stop the input(or loop).

I hope my answer could help you.

Comment: This is actually not my code attached here, just a program I found online. And, yes, EOF is the terminal sign of reading from file, however, the "file" here does not only mean a document in the computer, but more like a stream of data. Also: _"In the C Standard Library, the character reading functions such as getchar return a value equal to the symbolic value (macro) EOF to indicate that an end-of-file condition has occurred."_ (see: [EOF in wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/End-of-file))